# How to specify a Relative file path in web.xml file for my .ini file

Tags: java, relative-path, web.xml

Below is the web.xml path I added for WebApp.ini I am receiving file not found Exception but if I give the exact path i.e WAS container then war then its working.

```
<context-param>
        <description>
        </description>
        <param-name>InitFileName</param-name>
        <param-value>/WebApp.ini</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: did you try without the slash, so only <param-value>WebApp.ini</param-value> or <param-value>./WebApp.ini</param-value>?

Comment: Yes i already tried its not working.
My file present inside WebContent/Web-INF folder.